# Decrease memory consumption with objects inside python lists

Tags: python, django, numpy, memory

I'm currently using Docker-compose and numpy to populate a PostGIS database in Django.

The current issue is that I'm not sure what's consuming so much memory here:

```
tile_density = int(map_height * map_width / settings.NUM_OF_USERS)

    root2 = sqrt(2)
    map_radius = map_width / (2 * root2)
    lat_range = 90 / map_width  # 180 / map_width / 2
    lon_range = 90 / map_height  # 180 / map_height / 2

    print("Beginning migration creation")

    # Begin migration based on shade
    for i, y in enumerate(data):
        # y starts from top then goes to bottom

        # We have to imagine the current numpy array is like the coordinate system
        # Then translate it when creating user locations
        temp_users = []
        for x in y:
            # x is now a tile. x starts from left and moves to right
            # Points go up to 14 decimal places
            if x in (-200.0, 0.0):  # No data or no people
                continue

            # Calculate the 4 Points as boundaries for these users' coordinates.
            theta = np.arcsin(i / map_radius / root2)

            temp = np.arcsin((2 * theta + np.sin(2 * theta)) / pi)
            lat_range = (
                temp - lat_range,
                temp + lat_range
            )

            temp = pi * x / 2 / map_radius / root2 * np.cos(theta)
            lon_range = (
                temp - lon_range,
                temp + lon_range
            )

            # Add user
            for user in range(int(tile_density * x)):  # Number of users in tile
                temp_users.append(
                    User(
                        username=uuid4(),
                        password=make_password("test", None, "md5"),
                        first_name=get_first_name(),
                        last_name=get_last_name(),
                        location=Point(
                            uniform(lon_range[0], lon_range[1]),
                            uniform(lat_range[0], lat_range[1])
                        )
                    )
                )

            # Bulk add users to User model
            User.objects.bulk_create(temp_users)
            temp_users.clear()
```

The variable `data` is a numpy array with dtype Float32. As the iteration continues (starting from 10 GB of memory usage), the memory quickly increases from 10GB to 12GB and forcing docker to exit with code 137.

I can't tell what's actually increasing the amount of memory usage here. [The full code is here](https://github.com/Andrew-Chen-Wang/django-sample-user-locations/blob/master/public/utils.py). At the bottom, you'll see User(username etc.); User is an object that I've appended to a list `temp_users` which Django will bulk_create into the PostGIS db. Supposedly, the memory leaks are happening there, but I printed `sys.getsizeof(temp_users)` and I never get added memory since it's recycled in the for loop.

So what's actually causing the memory overload here? The shape of the Float32 numpy array is approximately 36000, 72143 (can't remember).

Comment: Well, without looking at your code, the array you describe will require (36000*72143*4*1e-9)gigabytes, so around 10GB

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, I but why is the memory usage always increasing? Shouldn't it be fluctuating once one iteration of the loop is done?